# SQL Server 2016 XML Shredding

Tags: openxml, sql-server-2016, xml-namespaces

Have been trying to figure this out for a while without success, read like 10 posts and some other examples and the MS help, not resonating, need to shred some xml data with the following format:

```
<ncf_report xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://cp.com/rules/client">
  <admin>
    <quoteback name="abcd">ABCD A</quoteback>
    <product_group>Abcd ABcd Abcd</product_group>
    <pnc_account>123456</pnc_account>
    <pnc_account_name>ABC</pnc_account_name>
    <product_reference>123456789</product_reference>
    <report_type>ABCDE</report_type>
    <status>ABCDE</status>
    <ownership>ABCD</ownership>
    <report_code>1234</report_code>
    <report_description>Abcde/report_description>
    <purpose>ABCDEFGH</purpose>
    <date_request_ordered>05/05/2020</date_request_ordered>
    <date_request_received>05/05/2020</date_request_received>
    <date_request_completed>05/05/2020</date_request_completed>
    <time_report_processed>1028</time_report_processed>
    <multiple_scores_ordered>false</multiple_scores_ordered>
    <vendor name="Abcd" address="Abcd" />
    <report>
      <sequence>0000000001</sequence>
      <count>0000000001</count>
    </report>
  </admin>
  <report>
    <alerts_scoring>
      <scoring>
        <score status="Abcd">
          <model_label>ABCD</model_label>
          <score>123</score>
          <rating_state>AB</rating_state>
          <classification> ABCD </classification>
          <reason_codes>
            <code>12</code>
            <description>ABCD</description>
          </reason_codes>
          <reason_codes>
            <code>12</code>
            <description>ABCD</description>
          </reason_codes>
          <reason_codes>
            <code>12</code>
            <description>ABCD ABCD ABCD</description>
          </reason_codes>
          <reason_codes>
            <code>12</code>
            <description>ABCD ABCD ABCD</description>
          </reason_codes>
        </score>
      </scoring>
      <general>ABCD ABCD ABCD ORIGINAL REPORT DATE: 12/12/2000</general>
      <general>ABCD ABCD ABCD</general>
      <general> ABCD ABCD ABCD</general>
      <general narrativeCode="Abcd Abcd">ABCD ABCD ABCD</general>
      <general narrativeCode=" Abcd Abcd">ABCD ABCD ABCD</general>
      <general narrativeCode=" Abcd Abcd">ABCD ABCD ABCD</general>
    </alerts_scoring>
    <vendor_dataset>
      <subjects>
        <subject type="Abcd" relationship_to_data="Abcd">
          <name type="Abcd">
            <first>XXXX</first>
            <middle>X</middle>
            <last>XXXX</last>
          </name>
          <birth_date>01/01/1900</birth_date>
          <ssn>999999999</ssn>
          <address type="Abcd" ref="1" />
          <address type="Abcd" ref="2" />
          <address type="Abcd" ref="3" />
        </subject>
      </subjects>
      <addresses>
        <address id="1">
          <street1>ABCD</street1>
          <city>ABCD</city>
          <state>AB</state>
          <postalcode>12345</postalcode>
          <zip4>1234</zip4>
          <date_first_at_address>01/02/1900</date_first_at_address>
          <date_last_at_address>01/02/1900</date_last_at_address>
        </address>
        <address id="2">
          <house>123</house>
          <street1>ABCDE</street1>
          <city>ABCDE</city>
          <state>AB</state>
          <postalcode>12345</postalcode>
          <zip4>1234</zip4>
          <date_first_at_address>00/00/1900</date_first_at_address>
          <date_last_at_address>00/00/1900</date_last_at_address>
        </address>
        <address id="3">
          <street1>ABCDE</street1>
          <city>ABCDE</city>
          <state>AB</state>
          <postalcode>12345</postalcode>
          <zip4>1234</zip4>
          <date_first_at_address>00/00/1900</date_first_at_address>
          <date_last_at_address>00/00/1900</date_last_at_address>
        </address>
      </addresses>
    </vendor_dataset>
    <summary>
      <date_oldest_trade>00/00/1900</date_oldest_trade>
      <date_latest_trade>00/00/1900</date_latest_trade>
      <date_latest_activity>00/00/1900</date_latest_activity>
      <includes_bankruptcies flag="true" date="02/02/2009" />
      <includes_other_records public_records="false" collection="true" consumer_statement="false" />
      <credit_range high="123456" low="1234" number_trade_lines="12" />
      **<account_status_counters>
        <account type="current" description="Pays Account as Agreed" status="1">12</account>
        <account type="current" description="Status Not Known" status=" ">7</account>
        <account type="former" description="Pays/Paid 30-60 Days or Max 2 Payments Past Due" status="2">5</account>
        <account type="former" description="Pays/Paid 60-90 Days or Max 3 Payments Past Due" status="3">4</account>
        <account type="former" description="Bad Debt" status="9">6</account>
      </account_status_counters>**
```

I currently going down the path of trying to use the xml procedure but I could not get to the finish line with openxml as well. Trying to extract data in  highlighted at bottom of xml

```
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hdoc OUTPUT, @CreditScoreXML 
SELECT * FROM OPENXML(@hdoc, '/<ncf_report xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://cp.com/rules/client">/admin/summary/account_status_counters')
WITH
(
  [Ref_Number] VARCHAR(10) 'product_reference',
  [current_account_type] VARCHAR(10) './account/@type',
  [current_account_type_description] VARCHAR(50) './account/@description',
  [current_account_type_description] VARCHAR(1) './account/@status'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define the namespace for your XML using `WITH XMLNAMESPACES` statement, then you can extract the values you need with `.value()`.

I don't understand exactly the information you are trying to extract, but this should put you on the right track (I only put the first row of your xml to save space, you should put the entire XML fragment in the `@xml` variable):

```
declare @xml xml set @xml='
    <ncf_report xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://cp.com/rules/client">
    ...
'

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://cp.com/rules/client' as ns1)
select 
 @xml.value('(ns1:ncf_report/ns1:admin/ns1:product_reference)[1]', 'varchar(10)') as Ref_Number
,@xml.value('(ns1:ncf_report/ns1:report/ns1:summary/ns1:account_status_counters/ns1:account[@type="current" and @status ="1"]/@description)[1]', 'varchar(50)') as CurrentDescription
,@xml.value('(ns1:ncf_report/ns1:report/ns1:summary/ns1:account_status_counters/ns1:account[@type="current" and @status ="1"])[1]', 'int') as CurrentStatus
,@xml.value('(ns1:ncf_report/ns1:report/ns1:summary/ns1:account_status_counters/ns1:account[@type="current" and @status =" "]/@description)[1]', 'varchar(50)') as CurrentDescription_2
,@xml.value('(ns1:ncf_report/ns1:report/ns1:summary/ns1:account_status_counters/ns1:account[@type="current" and @status =" "])[1]', 'int') as CurrentStatus_2
```

This sample query would extract:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response Andrea.  Does it matter if XML format varies across observations? 
In this case we have multiple current and former account status within but this will change on a per observation basis.

Comment: @Ricky This should not be a problem: what is important is that you have a rule (a filter) to select the data you want when there is a different number of <account> tags. In my answer I used as a sample filter `type="current" and @status ="1"`, but I don't know if this makes any sense in your scenario. If no <account> tag matches the filter then you'll get NULL in that column.

Comment: So this works for the XML fragment that I include within the declare statement so how do we apply to all records that I want to select